# How to show the message below the textbox using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created an application - it is mostly done but I have a small issue: How to show the message below the `textbox`.

If you click the edit button the `textbox` will come for every row that is for editable option but I want to show text remaining count below the `textbox` which one editable appear.

I did the following, but it's not working well.

```js
$(function() {

  $(".edit").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    var btn = $(this);
    var td = btn.closest("tr").find(".editable");


    //Save current text in td data attribute

    if (btn.text() === "edit") {
      //store the current value only on click of EDIT and not on save
      var currentValue = td.text();
      $(td).data("current-value", currentValue);
      td.html("<input type='text' value=" + currentValue + " />");
      btn.html("save");
    } else {
      if (td.find("input").val() == "") {

        alert("please fill the text box")
      } else {
        td.html(td.find("input").val());
        btn.html("edit");
      }
    }

    var text_max = 25;
    $(td.find("input")).html(text_max + ' characters remaining');

    $(td.find("input")).keyup(function() {
      var text_length = td.find("input").val().length;
      var text_remaining = text_max - text_length;
      td.find("input").next().add("div").html(text_remaining + ' characters remaining');


    });


  });

  $(".cancel").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    var td = $(this).closest("tr").find(".editable");

    //Read data attribute to get saved text
    var currentValue = $(td).data("current-value");
    if (currentValue != "") {
      td.html(currentValue);


      //Set attribute to empty string
      $(td).data("current-value", "");
    } else {


    }
    $(this).parents('tr').find(".edit").html("edit");
  });



});
```

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

li {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 2px;
  padding: 2px;
}

li a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 2px;
}

li a:hover {
  background-color: #111;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tabledata">
  <thead>
    <th>RecID</th>
    <th>Col1</th>
    <th>opt</th>
  </thead>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a>
        <div class="nestedtable">Tableshowing no need edit</div>
      </a><span class="editable">RecID1</span></td>
    <td>Val1.1</td>
    <td>
      <ul>
        <li> <a class="edit">edit</a></li>
        <li> <a class="cancel">cancel</a></li>
      </ul>


    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a>
        <div class="nestedtable">Tableshowings no need edit</div>
      </a><span class="editable">RecID2</span></td>
    <td>Val2.1</td>
    <td>
      <ul>
        <li> <a class="edit">edit</a></li>
        <li> <a class="cancel">cancel</a></li>
      </ul>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a>
        <div class="nestedtable">Tableshowing no need edit</div>
      </a><span class="editable">RecID3</span></td>
    <td>Val3.1</td>
    <td>
      <ul>
        <li> <a class="edit">edit</a></li>
        <li> <a class="cancel">cancel</a></li>
      </ul>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9KEGd/195/)**

Comment: Why you don't move `nestedtable` after `editable` in your `html` ?

Answer (score 0):

Just change the editable span element positioning setting it before nestedTable div

```js
$(function () {
  
    $(".edit").click(function (e) {
     e.preventDefault();
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        var btn = $(this);
        var td = btn.closest("tr").find(".editable");
        
   
        //Save current text in td data attribute
        
        if(btn.text() === "edit")
        {
        //store the current value only on click of EDIT and not on save
          var currentValue = td.text();
          $(td).data("current-value", currentValue);
         td.html("<input type='text' value="+currentValue+" />");
            btn.html("save");
        }
        else
        {
         if(td.find("input").val()==""){
        
        alert("please fill the text box")
        }else{
          td.html(td.find("input").val());
            btn.html("edit");
            }
        }
        
     var text_max = 25;
    $(td.find("input")).html(text_max + ' characters remaining');

    $(td.find("input")).keyup(function() {
        var text_length = td.find("input").val().length;
        var text_remaining = text_max - text_length;
        td.find("input").next().add( "div" ).html(text_remaining + ' characters remaining');
  
 
    });
    

    });
    
     $(".cancel").click(function (e) {
     e.preventDefault();  
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        var td = $(this).closest("tr").find(".editable");
        
        //Read data attribute to get saved text
        var currentValue = $(td).data("current-value");
        if(currentValue != "")
        {
         td.html(currentValue);
            

            //Set attribute to empty string
            $(td).data("current-value", "");
        }else{
        
        
        }
        $(this).parents('tr').find(".edit").html("edit");
    });
    
    

});
```

```css
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
}

li {
    float: left;
    margin-left:2px;
    padding:2px;
}

li a {
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin:2px;
}

li a:hover {
    background-color: #111;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tabledata">
    <thead>
        <th>RecID</th>
        <th>Col1</th>
        <th>opt</th>
    </thead>
    <tr>
    <td><span class="editable">RecID1</span><a><div class="nestedtable">Tableshowing no need edit</div></a></td>
        <td>Val1.1</td>
        <td>
        <ul>
        <li> <a class="edit">edit</a></li>
         <li> <a class="cancel">cancel</a></li> 
        </ul>
       
       
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><span class="editable">RecID2</span><a><div class="nestedtable">Tableshowings no need edit</div></a></td>
        <td>Val2.1</td>
        <td>    <ul>
        <li> <a class="edit">edit</a></li>
         <li> <a class="cancel">cancel</a></li> 
        </ul></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><span class="editable">RecID3</span><a><div class="nestedtable">Tableshowing no need edit</div></a></td>
        <td>Val3.1</td>
        <td>    <ul>
        <li> <a class="edit">edit</a></li>
         <li> <a class="cancel">cancel</a></li> 
        </ul></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Wrong...i want to show message only selected edit button's row textbox below

Comment: it's hard to understand what you really want, can you explain better?

Comment: please read my QA.  i want to show message only selected edit button's row textbox below  like this:http://jsfiddle.net/47a7A/4882/

Comment: @sarancheln check this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9KEGd/199/), I added a new paragraph and changed the javascript to change the value on keyup

Answer (score 0):

> `add()` method is used to *Create a new jQuery object with elements
>   added to the set of matched elements*

You can store your `remaning character` value in `:before` of the `editable` span like below:

```js
$(function() {

  $(".edit").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    var btn = $(this);
    var td = btn.closest("tr").find(".editable");
    //Save current text in td data attribute
    if (btn.text() === "edit") {
      //store the current value only on click of EDIT and not on save
      var currentValue = td.text();
      $(td).data("current-value", currentValue);
      td.html("<input type='text' value=" + currentValue + " />");
      btn.html("save");
    } else {
      if (td.find("input").val() == "") {

        alert("please fill the text box")
      } else {
        td.html(td.find("input").val());
        btn.html("edit");
        $('.editable').removeClass('showBefore');
      }
    }
    var text_max = 25;
    $(td.find("input")).keyup(function() {
      var text_length = $(this).val().length;
      var text_remaining = text_max - text_length;
      $(this).closest('.editable').attr('data-char', text_remaining).addClass('showBefore');
    });
  });
  $(".cancel").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    var td = $(this).closest("tr").find(".editable");
    //Read data attribute to get saved text
    var currentValue = $(td).data("current-value");
    if (currentValue != "") {
      td.html(currentValue);
      //Set attribute to empty string
      $(td).data("current-value", "");
    } else {}
    $(this).parents('tr').find(".edit").html("edit");
    $('.editable').removeClass('showBefore');
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  font: 13px Verdana
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

.editable.showBefore:before {
  content: attr(data-char) "character remaning";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -14px;
  width: 100%;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td,
th {
  padding: 6px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.editable {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}

li {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 2px;
  padding: 2px;
}

li a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 2px;
}

li a:hover {
  background-color: #111;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tabledata">
  <thead>
    <th>RecID</th>
    <th>Col1</th>
    <th>opt</th>
  </thead>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a>
        <div class="nestedtable">Tableshowing no need edit</div>
      </a><span class="editable">RecID1</span></td>
    <td>Val1.1</td>
    <td>
      <ul>
        <li> <a class="edit">edit</a></li>
        <li> <a class="cancel">cancel</a></li>
      </ul>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a>
        <div class="nestedtable">Tableshowings no need edit</div>
      </a><span class="editable">RecID2</span></td>
    <td>Val2.1</td>
    <td>
      <ul>
        <li> <a class="edit">edit</a></li>
        <li> <a class="cancel">cancel</a></li>
      </ul>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <a>
        <div class="nestedtable">Tableshowing no need edit</div>
      </a><span class="editable">RecID3</span></td>
    <td>Val3.1</td>
    <td>
      <ul>
        <li> <a class="edit">edit</a></li>
        <li> <a class="cancel">cancel</a></li>
      </ul>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```